# Converting string with polygon coordinates to lat / lng format

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, coordinates, data-conversion

I have a string with a list of polygon coordinates in the following format:

```
var myString = "(38.35870116756209, 38.27089903372614),(38.3339292947434, 38.2743322612652),(38.33944984782068, 38.3017980815777),(38.35829734627614, 38.297678208530826)";
```

I want to convert that string to an array with lat / lng coordinates, like this:

```
const polygonCoords = [
    { lat: 38.35870116756209, lng: 38.27089903372614 },
    { lat: 38.3339292947434, lng: 38.2743322612652 },
    { lat: 38.33944984782068, lng: 38.3017980815777 },
    { lat: 38.35829734627614, lng: 38.297678208530826 },
    { lat: 38.35870116756209, lng: 38.27089903372614 } // first coordinate again
];
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO the most elegant way to approach this problem, is to...

1. use [String.prototype.replaceAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) to convert your string format into a [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)-compatible 2-dimensional array string
2. use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert your array string to an actual array
3. use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to convert your array to the desired format
4. use [Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to duplicate a reference to the first coordinate and append

#### Working demo

```js
var myString = "(38.35870116756209, 38.27089903372614),(38.3339292947434, 38.2743322612652),(38.33944984782068, 38.3017980815777),(38.35829734627614, 38.297678208530826)";

// 1. Convert string format to 2-dimensional array
myString = '[' + myString.replaceAll('(', '[').replaceAll(')', ']') + ']';

// 2. Parse array
const myArray = JSON.parse(myString);

// 3. Convert array format to polygonCoords
const polygonCoords = myArray.map(v => ({lat: v[0], lng: v[1]}));

// 4. Duplicate reference to first coordinate and append
polygonCoords.push(polygonCoords[0]);

console.log("OUTPUT :");
console.log(polygonCoords);
console.log("NUMBER OF COORDINATES :");
console.log(polygonCoords.length);
```

Or, if you prefer minimal code over readability, you can combine the first 3 statements, like this :

```js
var myString = "(38.35870116756209, 38.27089903372614),(38.3339292947434, 38.2743322612652),(38.33944984782068, 38.3017980815777),(38.35829734627614, 38.297678208530826)";

// Convert string to polygonCoords
const polygonCoords = JSON.parse('[' + myString.replaceAll('(', '[').replaceAll(')', ']') + ']')
                          .map(v => ({lat: v[0], lng: v[1]}));
// Duplicate reference to first coordinate and append
polygonCoords.push(polygonCoords[0]);

console.log("OUTPUT :");
console.log(polygonCoords);
console.log("NUMBER OF COORDINATES :");
console.log(polygonCoords.length);
```

#### Note

`polygonCoords.push(polygonCoords[0])` does not actually duplicate the first coordinate object itself. Instead it copies a reference to the same object. So, if you change the values of coordinate `polygonCoords[0]`, you also change the values of coordinate `polygonCoords[length-1]` and vice versa. Considering these should always be identical in polygons, I favor this approach.

If you nonetheless want to duplicate the object itself rather than a reference to the object, you will need to clone it first. To do this, use `polygonCoords.push(Object.assign({}, polygonCoords[0]));` instead of `polygonCoords.push(polygonCoords[0])`.

Comment: Very detailed and working answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
myString.split('),').map(x => x.replace(/[\n/(\)\+]/g,'')).map(x => {
    let [lat, lng] = x.split(', ');
    return {lat, lng}
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```js
const string = "(38.35870116756209, 38.27089903372614),(38.3339292947434, 38.2743322612652),(38.33944984782068, 38.3017980815777),(38.35829734627614, 38.297678208530826)"

const coordinates = string.substring(1, string.length - 1).split('),(').map(s => {
 const [lat, lng] = s.split(', ').map(Number)
 return {lat, lng}
})

console.log(coordinates)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using basic JavaScript array methods like this:

```
var myString = "(38.35870116756209, 38.27089903372614), \
(38.3339292947434, 38.2743322612652), \
(38.33944984782068, 38.3017980815777), \
(38.35829734627614, 38.297678208530826)"

const strArray = myString.split(', ')        // Note the whitespace after the comma

let left = []; 
let right = []; 

strArray.forEach(str => {
    if(str[0] === '(') {
        left.push(str.substr(1, str.length -1))
    }
    if (str[str.length - 1] === ')') {
        right.push(str.substr(0, str.length -2))
    }
})

let polygonCoords = []; 
if(left.length === right.length) {
    for(let i = 0, n = left.length; i < n; i++) {
        polygonCoords.push({
            lat: left[i], 
            lng: right[i]
        }) 
    }
}

console.log(polygonCoords)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other provided answers, I wanted to add one that makes use of the named matching groups:

```js
const str = "(38.35870116756209, 38.27089903372614),(38.3339292947434, 38.2743322612652),(38.33944984782068, 38.3017980815777),(38.35829734627614, 38.297678208530826)"

const result = str.match(/\(.*?\)/g)
  .map(res => res.match(/((?<lat>[\d.]*), (?<lon>[\d.]*)\))/).groups)
  
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using regular expressions, it's a powerful tool!

To simplify the task I removed the const access modifier from polygonCoords
but you can always change it later in your code.
Here's my solution:

String with data:

```
var coords="(38.35870116756209, 38.27089903372614),(38.3339292947434, 38.2743322612652),(38.33944984782068, 38.3017980815777),(38.35829734627614, 38.297678208530826)"
```

here goes the conversion

```
coords=coords.match(/[^(),]+/g) //making a list of separate elements and removing commas and brackets

var polygonCoords=[] 

for(var i=0;i<coords.length;i+=2){
    polygonCoords.push( {lat:coords[i], lng:coords[i+1]} )
}
//creating objects with our data and putting them in polygonCoords
```

As output it gives me :
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLO2p.png)

Output of polygonCoords:

```
0: {lat: '38.35870116756209', lng: ' 38.27089903372614'}
1: {lat: '38.3339292947434', lng: ' 38.2743322612652'}
2: {lat: '38.33944984782068', lng: ' 38.3017980815777'}
3: {lat: '38.35829734627614', lng: ' 38.297678208530826'}
```

I hope it helps